# Python Django - Issue w/ View Request

Tags: python, django, view, request

I am building a test application using Django framework written in Python. I am trying to ask a question, have the user answer the question, then get the results of the User's selected answer. I am having an issue with the retrieving what the User has selected.

**models.py**

```
class Question(models.Model):
    passage = models.ForeignKey(Passage, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    questions_text = models.CharField(max_length=400)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.questions_text


class Choice(models.Model):
    correct_choices = (
        ("Correct", "Correct"),
        ("Incorrect", "Incorrect"),
    )
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    explain = models.ForeignKey(Explanation, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
     choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    correct = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=correct_choices, default='Incorrect')
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text

    def check_answer(self, choice):
        return self.choices_set.filter(id=choice.id, is_answer=True).exists()

    def get_answer(self):
        return self.choices_set.filter(is_answer=True)'''
```

**views.py**

```
def detail(request, question_id):
    try:
        question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id)
     except Question.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Sorry, Question does not exist")
    return render(request, 'index/details.html', {'question': question})
    
def result(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'index/results.html', {'question': question})
    
def answer(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_answer = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'index/details.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "Please make a Valid Selection.",
        })
    else:
        selected_answer.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('results', args=(question.id,)))'''
```

**results.html**

```
<h1>Passage / Equation:</h1>
<p>{{ question.passage }}</p>
</div>
<div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
<h1>Answer for Question: </h1>
<h1>{{ question.questions_text }}</h1>
<p>Your Choice was: **{{ choice.selected_answer }}** ##I believe this is the issue here but unable to 
figure it out##</p>
<ul>
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %} <br>
<li>&#9658; {{ choice.choice_text }}</li>
<li>&#9644; This answer was: <b>{{ choice.correct }}</b></li>
<li>&#9677; Explanation: {{ choice.explain }}</li>
{% endfor %}

**details.py**
<form action="{% url 'results' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ 
choice.id }}">
<label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}"><p>{{ choice.choice_text }}</p> 
</label><br>
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Submit Answer">
```

I would appreciate any feedback or assistance with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

First I would check if by the point you reach the result view, there is a record in your database with the choice selected. If there is, maybe the problem is that you are not passing the "choice" object to the template?

```
#You have this line but in the template
<p>Your Choice was: **{{ choice.selected_answer }}** ##I believe this is the issue here but unable to figure it out##</p>

#But in the render you only pass the question
return render(request, 'index/results.html', {'question': question})
```

Add this line before rendering result.html:

```
#Pass the choice to the context
choice = question.choice_set.all().first()
return render(request, 'index/results.html', {'question': question,'choice': choice})
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So it does point to the results view, and updating the view to include: ''' selected_answer.answer = str(selected_answer)''', it saves in the database. The issue still remains when trying to call the user's selection with the {{ selected_answer }} does not work. When trying to pass the render choice in the template, i get an error that Choice is not defined.

Comment: Try passing the choice along with the question in the context. I edited the answer with an example.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I should mention that I new to Django and programming as a whole. With your suggestion, it was able to pull the first choice on the results.html page but was not able to pull the selected_answer. I understand that I should not use the .first() cause that what it would do, pull the first choice, but we know it is working for the most part. So I tried to modify the code to see if it could pull the selected answer by changing it to selected_answer() but received an error since there is not table, it was assigned as a variable. It saves under the DB as choice.answer

Comment: Then probably you need a third model to store wich choice to what question selected the user. Because if you store the selected answer in a variable, you can use it only in your `def answer (request, question_id)` view. When you reach your `def result(...)` view, it doesn't exists anymore. So I'd make a `class ChoiceSelected(models.Model)` with the foreign keys to the user, the question and the choice selected. Then you can access the choice selected anywhere in your views.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. So I tried creating a new model and tried to update the view but it's unable to save the data to the DB. I understand what needs to be done, just having a hard time writing it out so the program knows what to do. I want the User to select a choice, submit it, the question_id and the selected_choice get saved to the new "Selection" model Question as Foreign Key and Selected as CharField. Then we use {{ Selection.selected }} to pull that data from the DB.

Comment: So I guess my question would be, how would I update the view so it recognizes the new model and post the selected choice to the newly created tables?

Comment: Seems like using '''selected_answer.answer = selected_answer.choice_text''' and {% if choice.answer %}  {{ choice.answer }} was able to generate the selected_answer without the new model. There is a slight bug with it but I'm happy with it for now. Thank you for your help.